# Is there a way to check subscribers number connected to pattern in redis?

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I want to check how many users are connected to my pubsub pattern. Is there a simple way to do it in Go? Thank you.

```
    pubsub := env.redisCli.PSubscribe(name)
    defer pubsub.Close()
```

I have tried this:

```
val, _ := env.redisCli.Do("pubsub", "numpat").Int()
```

But it shows me other patterns also and I want to count only in that specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The redis documentation states you can limit the result to a single subscription with the **NUMSUB** command, but this will not list clients that are subscribed to patterns:

> Returns the number of subscribers (not counting clients subscribed to patterns) for the specified channels.

The **NUMPAT** on the other hand will count all patterns all clients are connected to:

> Note that this is not just the count of clients subscribed to patterns but the total number of patterns all the clients are subscribed to.

(from https://redis.io/commands/pubsub)

I don't find a way to list all subscribers with their subscriptions in Redis. So the only way I can think of is to store that information in redis (or somewhere else) independently and manage it yourself.